# Load balancing strategies on nginx

Tags: cookies, nginx, load-balancing, web-storage

To tackle expanding server load I have came up with a solution to render plain HTML site for visitors of my site. So the visitors are routed to plain html site whereas registered users are routed to dynamic site.
To separate the two different user groups I have used cookies. The load balancer and web server I'm using is nginx.

The nginx conf looks like this:

```
set $cookie_set 0;
if ($http_cookie ~ 'mysite.com') {
        set $cookie_set 1;
}
location / {
        if ($cookie_set ~ 0) {
               proxy_pass http://static-site;
        }
        if ($cookie_set ~ 1) {
                proxy_pass http://dynamic-site;
        }
}
```

The mentioned strategy works, but it's not bulletproof. There are some situations where this doesn't work e.g. with browsers that don't support cookies and falsely created cookies.

There must be more sophisticated strategy of doing this. Any experiences, comments and ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is where a real load-balancer, such as HAProxy is needed.
with HAProxy, you can route traffic based on current backend farm capacity.

The configuration sniplet below forward the traffic to the static backend when the dynamic one start queueing.

```
frontend

 use_backend bk_static if { queue(bk_dynamic) ge 1 }
 default_backend bk_dynamic

backend bk_static

backend bk_dynamic
```

The same type of configuration could apply to a number of running sessions on bk_dynamic backend.

Baptiste

Comment: Cool. The only unwanted issue is that registered users will see visitor content if dynamic site starts queueing. I'm look for a persist solution to separate visitors and registered users that is not dependent on server load.